# Create dynamic element and document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I add a dynamic created element with jquery in current element.

```
<div>
   <script>
      LoadWidget("Hello");
   </script>
</div>

.
.
.
.

<script>
   function LoadWidget(name){
      //For example:
      var widget = $("<p />").html(name);
      document.write(widget.?????????);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking what should go in the `?????`s?

Comment: You just need to add the widget to the document. For example: `$('body').append(widget);`

Comment: @Cory $('body').append(widget); put my element at end <br />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually want to get the html of an element, you can do

```
widget[0].outerHTML
```

or, more jQuery-esque:

```
widget.wrap("<div>").parent().html()
```

However, it is probably better for you to use the jQuery `append` function to add your element to the page, by doing something like

```
$("body").append(widget)
```

Comment: widget[0].outerHTML not work in all browser:<br />
 <br/>
    Firefox (Gecko): 11 ....Released 2011-03-13 <br/>
    Chrome: 0.2 ...............Released 2008-09-02 <br/>
    Internet Explorer 4.0...Released 1997 <br/>
    Opera 7 ......................Released 2003-01-28 <br/>
    Safari 1.3 ...................Released 2006-01-12 <br/>
<br />
but widget.wrap("<div>").parent().html() is a good answer...

Comment: @OmidMafakher Yeah, if you can get away with it (i.e. know that you will always have it) the `[0].outerHTML` trick is a lot simpler, but wrapping it and getting the html of the parent is much more compatible.

Comment: @OmidMafakher Also, note that you can't put HTML tags inside comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
Add a `<div>` with an ID of `wiget` . This will be the container for the dynamically appended elements via your `LoadWidget()` function.

```
    <div>
<div id="widget"></div>

<script>
    LoadWidget("Hello");
</script>
</div>

            .
            .
            .
            .

<script>
function LoadWidget(name)
{
    if(name)
    {
                  /*
                   * Use the widget HTML element to place the name
                   * into the widget container
                   *
                   */

        $('#wiget').html('<p>'+name+'</p>');
                    /* OR */

                   /* $('body').html('<p>'+name+'</p>'); */

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: other developers want to use it and I don't know what is id of parent div.

Comment: so ur saying that you can't modify the HTML